# Labels in Print Composer

Tags: printing, qgis

Using QGIS 3.12.2

I would like to label my map in Print Composer using variables inside a shapefile layer.  When I open the expression editor the layer is there, but no way to extricate individual variables.

Can I use a variable from a layer in my map in my label?

Comment: you just use "attribute_name"  - what can't you do?

Comment: I've tried this:

`[% attribute( @lin,'STORMNAME')%]`

lin is the name of the layer and STORMNAME is what I want to display.  I checked the attribute table in QGIS and the STORMNAME is there, but this expression inside a label in Print Composer shows up blank.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `attribute` takes a `Feature` not a layer name. So you need to do something like:

```
[%  attribute(  get_feature( 'layer name','NAME', 'Sussex') ,'color')%]
```

to first acquire a feature then grab an attribute from it.